# ssh service showing activating state after upgrade the version of openssh 9.2pl

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arch-linux, linux-mint

I am using ubuntu 20.04 i have upgraded the openssh version but after upgrade the verion service showing activating state.

```
 ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Fri 2023-03-10 12:06:57 IST; 17s ago
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
    Process: 964649 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Cntrl PID: 964650 (sshd)
      Tasks: 5 (limit: 9429)
     Memory: 5.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             ├─964650 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups
             ├─964652 sshd: decoy [priv]
             ├─964785 sshd: decoy@pts/0
             ├─964786 -bash
             └─964794 sudo su
```

Comment: Welcome! Please [edit] your question to explain exactly how you upgraded OpenSSH.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.